# How can I set the slider to have a diffrent colour before the first handle, between the handles and after the second handle?

Tags: nouislider

I want to set a slider to allow people to set a ratio between things, I have set it up to read of the relevant values but am not sure how I would go about setting the colours to different in each section to make it more visually obvious what the slider is for.

So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#slider").noUiSlider({
    start: [ 30, 70 ],
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100
 }
});
```

```css
#slider .noUi-base {
    background: red;
}
#slider .noUi-background {
 background: blue;
}
#slider .noUi-connect {
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://refreshless.com/nouislider/source/distribute/jquery.nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://refreshless.com/nouislider/source/distribute/jquery.nouislider.all.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: If you are using Angular 2+  noUISlider component : 
Add this in the component that you are using to override the css from child component.

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 2+  noUISlider component : 
Add this in the component that you are using to override the css from child component.

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})